# Find the ratio of the diagonal cut

Tags: geometry

> If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and point $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ then in what ratio does the intersection of diagonal $AC$ and the straight line $DM$ split $AC$?

I was thinking of Ceva's theorem, but this isn't a triangle. Is there some similar theorem or formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

$\triangle{EAM}$ and $\triangle{ECD}$ are similar where $E$ is the intersection point between $DM$ and $AC$.

Comment: Got it - 1:2 ratio. But how did you see that EC and AM relate instead of EC and EM for example? (+1) Great answer, great hint!

Comment: @Amad27: Since we are dealing with a parallelogram, similar triangles are easy to get. In our example, $AE:CE=AM:CD=1:2$. (sorry, but I don't really get your question...)

Comment: It makes sense, dont worry about it. I have another GEO question if you are interested; a little tougher about triangles.